# Dynimically add html element with bind onclick event to other dynimically added html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind

I know a part of this question was already asked and i followed the answer of it but it stills doesn't work (the added html elements aren't displayed), could you help me ? 
I want the label and the entry to be only displayed when an option of the dropdown menu is selected

Here's the html part :

```
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value='1'>Doesn't repeat</option>
    <option value='2' id="repeatChange">Daily</option>
    <option value='3' id="repeatChange">Weekly</option>
    <option value='4' id="repeatChange">Biweekly</option>
    <option value='5' id="repeatChange">Monthly</option>
</select>
<label id="labelHowMuch">How many times ?</label>
<input type="text" id="repeatHowMuch" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
```

And here's the jquery part :

```
$('#labelHowMuch').remove();
$('#repeatHowMuch').remove();
$(document).on('click', '#repeatChange' , function() {
    $('#labelHowMuch').append($('#dropDown'));
    $('#repeatHowMuch').append($('#labelHowMuch'));
});
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document.

Comment: You should not have multiple elements with  the same id,

Comment: oh okay, so if i bind on class it may works ?

Comment: I answered you ^^

Comment: Why are you trying to append a `<select>` element to a `<label>` element and append any element to an `<input>` element?

Comment: I was trying that because it worked in an other part of the code, but not with a <select> element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct way you did many errors:

```js
$('#labelHowMuch').hide();
$('#repeatHowMuch').hide();
$(document).on('change', '#dropDown' , function() {
    if($(this)[0].value != 1){
        $('#labelHowMuch').show();
        $('#repeatHowMuch').show();
    }
    else{
        $('#labelHowMuch').hide();
        $('#repeatHowMuch').hide();    
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="dropDown">
    <option value='1'>Doesn't repeat</option>
    <option value='2'>Daily</option>
    <option value='3'>Weekly</option>
    <option value='4'>Biweekly</option>
    <option value='5'>Monthly</option>
</select>
<label id="labelHowMuch">How many times ?</label>
<input type="text" id="repeatHowMuch" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"/>
```

Comment: You should highlight the errors/incorrect code and Why. You are answering for readers and not just OP

Comment: Thanks you, it works ! I thought my code would work because i used the remove/append in an other part of this project and it worked fine ^^

Comment: Mark it as answer accepted if it helped you! I just improved the code to support when the selected option is "doesn't repeat"

Comment: I have the time limit to wait, if i haven't, i'd already marked it as answer.  
And thanks for your improvment for readers but i already did that in my code